# SQL statement like ? or

Tags: sql

I have this sql statement

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE first_name LIKE ?
```

It selects the customers from a search field by first name. I want to also search by last name but I cannot do it.
I use this code and it doesn't work

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE (first_name LIKE ?) OR (last_name LIKE ?)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please explain what « doesn’t work » with your query, with sample data and expected output

Comment: Please provide sample data, results that define what "doesn't work" means, and a database tag.

Comment: Dear friend, First please provide your sql platform. Like sql server/mysql/oracle. Then provide the code which you have tried. This will be helpful to answer quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE (first_name LIKE ?) OR (last_name LIKE ?)
```

Should work -- but you need to pass the parameter in twice.  You could get around this with named parameters:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE (first_name LIKE :pattern) OR (last_name LIKE :pattern)
```

Or by using a subquery/CTE:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT ? as pattern) p
WHERE (c.first_name LIKE p.pattern) OR (c.last_name LIKE p.pattern);
```

Or, you could possible implement almost equivalent logic with a single expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE first_name || ' ' || last_name LIKE '%' || ? || '%';
```

The latter isn't exactly equivalent, but it would be equivalent in many circumstances.